# JavaScript block scope vs function

Tags: javascript

Are following snippets exactly equal? If no what is the deference?

```
var x = (function() {
    ... //a
    return function(){
        ... //b
    };
})();
```

vs.

```
var x;
{
    ... //a
    x = function(){
        ... //b
    };
}
```

Comment: @JohnS please don't paste code into the title like that. Post your code into the body.

Comment: @JohnP You are right but your title is too generic, it's like "What's the problem with my code?"

Comment: @JohnS but that is what you're asking. Pasting the code into the title does not make it readable. Feel free to come up with a better problem statement for your question

Comment: @JohnP Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: @JohnS That's 3 years old. I've only been active for a couple of months. Also that question title is much more readable than what you had put up. Like I said before, please do update your question if you have a better title :) It just needs to be clear and readable

Comment: @JohnP I changed it, what now?

Comment: @JohnS well, nothing. You've already marked this question as answered. Now it just helps other people with the same question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a major difference: In JavaScript, blocks don't induce a new variable scope. Therefore, you can't define private variables in the `// a` code block. Compare

```
var x = (function() {
    var v = 42;
    return function(){
        return v;
    };
})();
// v; would yield ReferenceError: v is not defined, so you need to call x
```

and

```
var x;
{
    var v = 42;
    x = function(){
        return v;
    };
}
// v is 42 here, that's not what's intended.
```

Answer (score 0):

One major difference is that at the time of executing `...//a` , x doesn't exist. Now in your case, in both cases it is `undefined` but generally speaking it's possible to access x variable during `...//a` while in the first case it's not.

Otherwise in your circumstances it's pretty same. After all in your case the code is basically refactored into a separate function just like in any other language.

Comment: One more thing: `{var z = 1;}` will create a variable z in the window namespace, while `(function(){var z = 2;}())` will not pollute the global namespace. That's why the function option is preferred